# Maximo: Where do service.log entries get stored?

Tags: debugging, logging, maximo

I have automation scripts in Maximo 7.6.1.1.

The scripts have lines that are meant for logging/debugging:

`service.log("Here is a debugging note.")`.

- The Log Level is set to ERROR

**Where do these log entries get stored?** How can I view them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `service.log()` logs to INFO by default, but there is also an option for the other logging levels (`service.log_error()`, `service.log_warn()`, `service.log_info()`, and `service.log_debug()`. If your actual logger (not the "logging" entry on the automation script page) is set to ERROR, the `log()` statements won't go anywhere. You will need to turn your logging level down to INFO or DEBUG.

To change the logging settings for this specific logger, you need to go to the Logging application (located where user89 points out, System Configuration -> Platform Configuration -> Logging), highlight the autoscript logger in the top table (which is bound to the "maximo.script" logger, for reference), and then click to add a row to the bottom table. In that bottom table, name the entry the same as your automation script name (so it's maximo.script.<scriptname>). This is the logger the `service` logger uses. A word of note, even after applying the settings, I sometimes could not see my logging until I restarted the JVM.

As noted by user89, the logs are generally configured to go into the `System.Out` log file in the WebSphere node profile\logs\<mxe.name> directory. However, you can also have them go somewhere else (but likely still on the server, unless you have a mapped directory somewhere you can use). While you are adding that script logging entry from above, you could add the rolling file appender and then use the action on the left bar to "set the root logger directory". Then your logging statements will *also* go to the file listed in the appender into the directory you set as the root.

Comment: The problem with loggers other than Console is that when errors happen, Maximo has to catch them in order to log them -- and sometimes Maximo doesn't catch them. So, as a personal rule, I avoid the other appenders. And for the Conversion Pattern for Console, I recommend taking out the timestamp, since WebSphere will put its own in there anyway, and instead put `[%3c]` to show the category (logger) that the message was logged against.

Answer (score 1):

You can view these logs in SystemOut.log file.

Note: Also, please add this script to AutoScript root logger (System Configuration -> Platform Configuration -> Logging)